# python requests redirects to another url

Tags: python, parsing, redirect, python-requests

I'm sorta new to programming, I'm trying to make a parsing "bot" for a TV series list site, but having problems with the first part - getting the right page source.
More specifically, I'm trying to get a list of episodes from "www.lostfilm.tv/browse.php?cat=145", but with this code:

```
import requests
lf_game_url = 'http://www.lostfilm.tv/browse.php?cat=145'
lf_game_source = requests.get(lf_game_url, allow_redirects=False).text
```

I get another's page source ("www.yandex.ru"), and

```
request = requests.get(lf_game_url, allow_redirects=False)
print request.status_code
```

is 301, though any browser works fine!
Maybe I'm missing something, like an HTML header I need to pass to the request, but I'm stuck and will be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, which was pretty simple. Just had to add a fake "User-Agent" header to the request, like:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
...
request = requests.get(lf_game_url, allow_redirects=False, headers=headers)
```